# Django models retrieve specific records daily

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models

I have a django application that will retrieve and display 3 records (questions) to all users of the app during a 24hr window beginning at a specific time, say 11:00 daily. Preferably, I would like to randomise the list of records or just use the question id which autoincrements. There are more than 14,000 records.

I can retrieve records from the db and randomly display those records. However, every http get request (refreshing browser window) retrieves different questions
Models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.conf import settings

    class Questions(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
        answer = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
        question_used = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

Views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views.generic import CreateView, View
    from .models import *
    from wallet.models import UserWallet

    class DailyDrawView(View):
        template_name = 'daily_draw/daily_draw.html'

        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            que_attempt = DailyDraw.objects.filter(user=request.user, is_active=True).last()
            question_objs = Questions.objects.all().order_by('?')[:3]
            points = WinnerPoint.objects.last().amount
            return render(request, self.template_name {'question_objs':question_objs, 'que_attempt':que_attempt, 'points':points })
```

At a particular time daily, retrieve 3 records. Display those records to all users throughout a 24hrs period. Update those 3 rows so that those same records are not displayed again. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: With Django views you will have a new random set of 3 questions for request. If you want to get around this you will need to cache the 3 random questions at some point. This could be a file or a database record of some kind.

Comment: You can add an `asked_at` field to your `Question` model and check if it has expired or not.

Comment: @EmettSpeer, caching sounds like the best option at the moment. Would it be possible to populate the cache at the expiration of the timeout value instead of waiting for a client side request?

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was to create a separate table that stored question ids and date. Then compared the time when a request is made to a constant time when new questions should be generated. If the time was past 24hrs, I updated the reference table with a new row of question ids and the current date.

I can post a more comprehensive answer if anyone requires it.

Comment: Please definitely elaborate :) This will be a good answer with a little more detail/code